# Stop page refreshing after updating row through jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

My data is updated successfully and after updated it shows on table in browser with updated row. but the problem is after updated it reload the page. please suggest me what can i do to stop refreshing my page? because i used ajax jquery to update my row.

i used page reload function in ajax success method to reload the page, but without reloading page my data is not updating.

add_user.php

```
    <?php
    
    $sql="SELECT * from users where role = 'tm'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    
    
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <center>
        <h5 class="card-header info-color white-text text-center py-4"><strong>Users Details</strong> </h5>
        </center> <br/> 
        
        
    
    
    <?php
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {?>
        <table class="table table-striped" id="example" align="center">
            
                <thead>
                <tr class="justify-content-center">
                    <th style="padding:7px">Name</th>
                    <th style="padding:7px">Email</th>
                    <th style="padding:7px">Position</th>
                    <th style="padding:7px">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            
                <tbody id="myTable">
    <?php
        echo "<tr>";
        
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
            echo "<td style='padding:7px'>".$row["name"]."</td>";
            echo "<td style='padding:7px'>".$row["email"]."</td>";
            echo "<td style='padding:7px'>".$row["position"]."</td>";
            ?>
            <td style='padding:7px'><button class="btn btn-info"  onclick="deleteUser('<?php echo $row['id'];?>')"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> DELETE </button> |
            <button class="btn btn-info  edit" value="View Data" edit-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> EDIT </button> |        
            <button class="btn btn-info  abc" value="View Data" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">  <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> VIEW DATA </button>
    
            </td>
    
    
            <?php echo "</tr>"; 
        } ?>
                </tbody>
    
                
        <?php
         echo "</table>";
         
     }
    else
        {
            echo "No row exists";
        }
    ?>
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              
              <h4 class="modal-title"> </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="displaydata">
              
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="modal fade" id="editmodal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              
              <h4 class="modal-title"> Update Details </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="editbody">
            <div class="container">
            <form method="POST" id="editform">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" id="userid">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="userName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Position</label>
            <input type="text" name="position" class="form-control" id="position" >
            </div>
              <input type="hidden" name="update" value="update" >
            </form>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            
              
              <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-info  update" name="insert" id="insert" value="Update">
               <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-info  update" name="insert" id="insert" onclick="updatedetail()"> Update </button> -->
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.abc').on('click',function(){
                var dataId = $(this).attr("data-id");
                        $.ajax({
                                method: "POST",
                                url: "single_user.php",
                                // data : $('#displaydata').serialize(),
                                dataType: "html",
                                data:{ dataId : dataId}, 
                                success: function(response)
                                {
                                $('#displaydata').html(response);
                                $('#myModal').modal('show');        
                                }           
                                });
                            });
    
            $('.edit').on('click',function(){
                    var editId = $(this).attr("edit-id");               
                        $.ajax({
                                 method: "POST",
                                 url: "edit_user.php",                           
                                 data: {editId: editId},
                                 dataType: "json",
                                 success: function(response)
                                 {  
                                     $('#userid').val(response.id); 
                                     $('#userName').val(response.name);
                                     $('#email').val(response.email);
                                     $('#position').val(response.position);
                                     $("#editmodal").modal('show');                                 
                                 }                           
                                 });
                            });
    
            $('.update').on('click',function(){
                $.ajax({
                        method:"POST",
                        url: "edit_user.php",
                        data:$('#editform').serialize(), 
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(response)
                        {
                            $('#userName').val(response.data.name);
                            $('#email').val(response.data.email);
                            $('#position').val(response.data.position);
                            $('#editmodal').modal('hide');
                            location.reload(true);
                        }
                            });
                        });
    
                        $('#example').DataTable({
                            scrollY: 370,
                            "columnDefs" : [{
                                "targets" : [3],
                                "orderable" : false,
                                "searchable" :false
                            }]
                        });
                        });
    
        function deleteUser($id) {
        var ask = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
        if (ask) {
    
            window.location.href = "del_user.php?id="+$id;
    
        }
    }
    </script>
```

edit_user.php

```
    <?php
    include('db.php');
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
    {
        // not logged in
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit();
    }
    
        if(isset($_POST['editId']))
        {
            $id=$_POST['editId'];
            $query="SELECT id,name,email,position from `users` where id = '$id' ";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            echo json_encode($row);
        }
    
        if(isset($_POST['update']))
        {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $position = $_POST['position']; 
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            
            
            $query1 = "UPDATE `users` SET name='$name',email='$email', position='$position' WHERE id='".$id."'";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query1);
            $query="SELECT id,name,email,position from `users` where id = '$id' ";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            echo json_encode(['status'=> 'success','data'=>$row]);           
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: You also have a sneaky `location.reload(true);` in there on the `.update` callback... which can't be helping matters.

Comment: "but the problem is after updated it reload the page"... yes that's true. What do you think the line `location.reload(true)` is for? Clue is in the name...

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the submit event on your button in your onClick event listeners:

```
.on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // this prevents the submit
  ... rest of your code
}
```

Comment: The "update" button is outside the form so this won't apply

Comment: That sneaky premature end form tag ;) Although hard to spot in that pile of mess called code in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Convert the submit button to a regular button or follow the above answer to `preventDefault` so it does not do a full page post and refreshes the page - Discussion below, refers to my misunderstanding and poor code-block reading skills ;)

Comment: Revised the answer to be coherent, the selectors mismatch between CSS and the HTML. Notice the class names are class="btn btn-info update" and id="insert" ( Original code from the post)

Comment: You misunderstand the difference between using an ID or CLASS for a selector. He does not need to be using the #id, when he already handles it correctly with a .class selector. Just because an element has an id, does not dictate that all selectors must use that id. How else do you ever expect to attach a handler to multiple items of a class?

Comment: Agreed with the comment, revised - Sometimes you have to eat humble pie - This threw me off 
- `    <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-info  update" name="insert" id="insert" value="Update">` It doesn't matter if you use Class selectors or ID's, i assumed they had mixed id and class . Re-visited the original ask and selectors are working properly, either preventDefault or turn the submit to a simple button.

Comment: Yeah, the question's code is kind of a mess to look at, and it had me going in loops as well ;-)